# How to set a layer as edited to call draw:edited

Tags: javascript, leaflet, edit, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to create markers on a map manually with Leaflet.Draw . 
When I add a marker with Leaflet.Draw, in the draw:created handler, I want to open a popup where a form is created.

Far from here, everything works and I can handle and save the creation of that popup and marker in database.

The twist here is when I want to edit it :

I click on the edit button, it makes the marker editable, I click on it to open the popup with form . I change the message in the popup , I click on the Edit Toolbar Save Button that will call the draw:edited handler.

Unfortunately my marker hasn't moved and is, because of that, not considered as an edited layer.

How is it possible to set that marker as "Edited" to be considered edited by the draw:edited handler even if it hasn't moved ?

In fact, how does those handlers work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Leaflet.Draw source, it hooks the `dragend` event on a marker like this

```
_onDragEnd: function (e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.edited = true;
        this._map.fire(L.Draw.Event.EDITMOVE, {layer: layer});
    }
```

You can set the `layer.edited` property (where `layer` is your marker) in your code.

Comment: Why is it possible for me to forget to go check the code ! Really sorry for my mistake ! I thank you a lot !